# Problema al otorgar permisos en DB-PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

buen día.

Estoy teniendo problemas al otorgar todos los permisos a un usuario sobre una base de datos que estoy creando. Uso PostgreSQL 9.6.

1. Primeramente creo mi usuario de esta manera: `CREATE USER springappuser WITH PASSWORD 'pspringappuser';`
2. La base de datos la creo así: `CREATE DATABASE springapp;`
3. Para hacer la asignación del permiso uso lo siguiente: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA springapp TO springappuser;`

Entiendo que la parte de **IN SCHEMA** está mal, pero buscando en la documentación no he podido encontrar como hacerlo sobre la base de datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`springapp` no es un schema, es una base de datos.

Lo que quieres hacer es dar privilegios sobre todas las tablas de un schema dentro de esa base de datos, que supongo sería el schema `public`.

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO springappuser;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO springappuser;
```

Esto se hace habiendo entrado ya a la base de datos que creaste. Si estás usando psql, se haría con

```
\d springapp
```